# How to auto-click the retry button after 3 seconds by Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

How to auto-click the retry button after 3 seconds?

https://msg.cityline.com/LSPS2023HK-3fad52ed-6629-4777-9f2d-17b707dd723f.html?loc=%2FutsvInternet%2FLSPS2023HK%2Fhome%3Flang%3DEN

```
<button id="btn-retry-en-1" class="btn_cta" type="button" onclick="javascript:goEvent()">請重試 Retry<span id="remainTime1">(6)</span></button>
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout(<function that clicks the button>, 3000)`?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
let btnToClick = document.querySelector("#btn");

let t = setInterval(() => {
//it clicks the btn at every 1 second
  btnToClick.click();
},1000);

//if any event occurs then clear out the setInterval reference t
 setTimeout(() => {
    clearTimeout(t);
 },3000)

function demo() {
  console.log("clicked")
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="demo()">click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! 
Fun fact is it seems work on Google Chrome and Edge but not on firefox lol

Comment: But In my firefox browser it is working

Comment: I used console firefox is working, but when I turned into tampermonkey and it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to Tampermonkey:

```
(function() {
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("btn-retry-en-1").click(), 3000);
})();
```

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// For demo purposes - countdown function
let countdown = setInterval(() => {
  const timer = document.getElementById("remainTime1");
  let seconds = Number(timer.textContent.charAt(1));
  seconds--;
  timer.textContent = `(${seconds})`;
}, 1000);

// For demo purposes - click handler function
function goEvent() {
  clearInterval(countdown);
  document.querySelector("dialog").showModal();
}

// Add this to Tampermonkey
(function() {
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("btn-retry-en-1").click(), 3000);
})();
```

```css
:root {
  font: 2ch/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-retry-en-1" class="btn_cta" type="button" onclick="javascript:goEvent()">請重試 Retry<span id="remainTime1">(6)</span></button>

<!-- For demo purposes -->
<dialog>
  <form method="dialog">
    <p>The "Retry()" button was clicked after 3 seconds.</p>
    <p>Countdown on "Retry()" button should be frozen at (3).</p>
    <button>OK</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried and it also worked! However when I turned to https://msg.cityline.com/PU20BP23.html and it doesn't worked

Comment: The website blocks retries that are less than 3 seconds. JavaScript `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` functions are not precise, so give it a little more time by changing 3000 to 3500 in the `setTimeout()` function.